Could a universe be expanding if its physics were scale invariant?
Imagine a universe where every field is massless and has scale-invariance. Would the expansion/contraction of the universe still be happening there? would it be detectable? Would it affect the evolution of said massless fields?
My attempt for a yes
The expansion/contraction of the universe has to do with its energy content... So I think that a universe filled with scale-invariant matter would still be gravitating onto itself and hence contracting.
My attempt for a no
Even if it were contracting, how could we know? If physics is scale-invariant, it would literally be unobservable, the expansion/contraction of the universe would be a gauge transformation. I understand that "unobservable" doesn't mean much in a universe with massless fields, because observers are massive. I guess the question is: would the expansion of the universe have a physical effect in the evolution of its scale invariant matter content?

If every field is massless where does the mass-energy in the universe such as scale-invariant matter come from?

How is the question of where matter came from any less answerable when it's massless?

massless fields have a stress-energy tensor just like massive fields, so they also source gravity. Famously Einstein predicted that light bends due to gravity, precisely because of this.

It depends how zealous you want to be about imposing scale invariance. Massless fields are fields that would lead to "physics being scale invariant" if you placed them in flat space with no dynamical gravity. I'm less sure about what happens in conformal gravity but any universe governed by general relativity will have physical laws breaking scale invariance because Newton's constant is dimensionful.
So yes. Expansion of the universe would still happen with only massless fields. As you have probably heard, the first several thousand years after the Big Bang were radiation dominated. The universe expanded during this period as it would in the idealization you propose that has no baryonic matter at all. Any observer able to detect a photon would see cosmological redshift for instance.
The main objection I can think of is that this hypothetical universe (while clearly not static) could never be observed to be expanding because the existence of observers requires the introduction of at least one massive field even if its only excitations are localized in a tiny place. But even this doesn't necessarily sound true to me. A universe with massless fields + GR will be able to form black holes and a network of black holes making up a brain is not the craziest idea I've ever heard.

This is a roundabout way of asking what a photon "observes" (or any other particles without a rest mass) producing pseudo-paradoxes in special relativity (for example, does a photon view every other photon as moving at c or as stationary?), just this time, it is a "paradox" in General Relativity.
The solution is that massless particles cannot be an inertial frame of reference, since they have no rest mass. The question literally has no answer because it assumes massless particles to be capable of being an inertial frame of reference.
